# Get Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER variable and display it in angular application

Tags: angular, jenkins

I deploy an angular application by Jenkins and I want to display the build number in the footer of the page. I know that while Jenkins is running the job, it sents a system environment variable [BUILD_NUMBER](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project).
I read some articles but none is saying how can we get this variable from the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround.

You can use pre and post build event to replace a version-tag in `environment.prod.ts` file.

```
export const environment = { production: true, system: 'prod', version: '%VERSION%' };
```

install npm-replace:

```
npm install replace --save-dev
```

package.json

```
"build:prod": "ng build --env=prod", 
"prebuild:prod": "replace '%VERSION%' $VERSION src/environments/environment.prod.ts", 
"postbuild:prod": "replace $VERSION '%VERSION%' src/environments/environment.prod.ts",
```

In jenkins run the following command

```
VERSION="$BUILD_NUMBER" npm run build:prod
```

Reference: [Request: Method to pass environment variables during build vs file.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4318#issuecomment-318359461)

**UPDATE**

Another way to achieve mentioned behavior is to use `sed` utility which is pre-installed in Linux.
You can follow these steps

1. Update `environment.prod.ts` to have a pre-defined key. Let's suppose `jenkinsBuildNO`. e.g

   `export const environment = { production: true, system: 'prod', version: 'jenkinsBuildNO' };`
2. Create another step in jenkins to update `jenkinsBuildNO` in `environment.prod.ts` with Build No. or something other.

   `sed -i -e 's/jenkinsBuildNO/%BUILD_NUMBER%/g' src/environments/environment.prod.ts`
3. start angular build. `ng buld --prod`
4. Update build no with our pre-defined key `jenkinsBuildNO` in
   `environment.prod.ts`

   `sed -i -e 's/%BUILD_NUMBER%/jenkinsBuildNO/g' src/environments/environment.prod.ts`

Comment: I followed these instructions and I got this as a value of VERSION : src/environments/environment.prod.ts. Why ?

Comment: I saw that there are many npm packages to replace strings I tried many of them and none of them worked for me. Any help ?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Jenkins is on Amazon Linux AMI and the build is done on docker image Ubuntu 14

Comment: @Souad I've updated answer, please check if it works for you. I've tested it on my own machine it worked.

Comment: thank you. I got it with this  : `'s/jenkinsBuildNO/'"%BUILD_NUMBER%"'/g' ` there are double quotes arround the variable big thanks !