# How to display application build version in an angular application

Tags: angular, jenkins, build, versioning

I have a jenkins pipeline which builds & deploy an angular application.
Is it possible to introduce a build parameter from Jenkins during build and display it in the angular application?

Edit:
The purpose is to introduce a parameter at the build time in jenkins pipeline which will take input during build time for describing the issue (for example: JIRA number of an issue) for which this build is getting created. It is then needed to display this issue/bugfix number in the angular application so that the user can see this fix number in the application footer and is sure about the fix deployed in the application. I hope to clarify the problem.

I started with available environment variable build number to start with & tried to use following script in Jenkins pipeline script stage('Replace'){ agent any when { environment name: 'showVersionCheckout', value: 'true'} steps {

```
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xyz', url: 'https://abcd.git']]])
                script {
                    sh "sed -i -e 's/VERSION/${env.version}/g' src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
            }
    }
```

In Angular app: export const environment = { production: false, VERSION: '0.0.2' }
So when the Jenkins pipeline builds the angular application, i still see the old value of 0.0.2 instead of what we replaced using sed.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Try to extend your question, YES would be the best answer to this question, but might not help you as expected.

Comment: @JanZahradnik - i tried to describe the problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asking for but i do the following in my applications. I have a  custom webpackconfig and define theses variables:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'APP_VERSION': JSON.stringify(packageJSON.version),
            'APP_LASTCOMMIT': JSON.stringify(childProcess.execSync('git rev-parse HEAD').toString())
        })
    ]
}
```

environment.ts:

```
declare var APP_VERSION;
declare var APP_LASTCOMMIT;
export const environment = {
    appName: 'WebCommander-DEV',
    appVersion: APP_VERSION,
    appLastCommit: APP_LASTCOMMIT,
    production: false,
};
```

Im sure you can adjust this procedure to pass your jenkins build-id into the building process

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Jenkins, but `TeamCity` has a built-in prebuild step called *File content replacement* and in `Gitlab CI` you can use list of predefined variables in your script, so I am using `sed` to the rest:

```
sed -i "s|regex to be replaced|replacement with $VARIABLE|" fileToBeModified.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display build number in angular applicaton using link
[Get Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER variable and display it in angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081042/get-jenkins-build-number-variable-and-display-it-in-angular-application?rq=1)